# pop() operation in Circular Queue. How do i actually remove the item?

Tags: c++, queue

I am trying to implement a simple circular queue using array in C++. Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

int  pop();
void push(int );
const int arrayLength = 8;
int inputArray[arrayLength] = {0};
int queueFront=0,queueBack=0;

void push(int theElement)
{
  //Check if the push causes queue to overflow
     if  (((queueBack + 1 ) % arrayLength) == queueFront)
 {
     std::cout<<"Queue is full."<<std::endl;
     return ;
 }
 inputArray[queueBack] = theElement;
     queueBack = (queueBack + 1) % arrayLength;
}


 int pop()
 {
   //Check if queue  is already empty

   if ( queueFront == queueBack )
   {
    std::cout<<"Queue is empty."<<std::endl;
   }

       std::cout<<inputArray[queueFront]<<" removed."<<std::endl;
   queueFront = (queueFront + 1 ) % arrayLength;



 }

int main()
{
  for ( int i =0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
      std::cout<<inputArray[i]<<std::endl;
  }
  push(1);
  push(2);
  push(3);
  pop();
  push(5);

      //printing arrayelements
  for ( int i =0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    std::cout<<inputArray[i]<<std::endl;
  }
 }
```

I get the following output when i run:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1 removed.
1
2
3
5
0
0
0
0

Question 1:
1. How do i actually remove the item in pop() operation?
2. Is my implementation correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you implement a real class instead of using global vars?

Comment: if you want to see the content of the queue, why don't you only iterate from queueFront to queueBack?

Comment: If you cannot use anything else than constant arrays, you can only put a known value in place of the old that says "empty", like -1 if you are dealing with natural integers only.

Comment: @segfolt I understand that making use of the destructor of the Class would be the right way to go. However i wanted to know given an array , how can one actually delete the element using pop()

Comment: What do you mean by "actually remove an item"?  What would it mean for an item to be un-actually removed?

Comment: @ScottHunter , when i iterate over the array , i shouldn't see the element that has been popped

Comment: @aba123: what should you see in its place? As Djon says, you'll need to put that there.

Answer (score 0):

Given that pop() still alters the queue after determining it is empty, answer to #2 is "no".

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have to remove anything. It is a circular queue, and you need to go from `queueFront` to `queueBack`. In your case, initially your queue is `1 2 3` and later it becomes `2 3 5` but contents of the array were `1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0` earlier and later after you pop they remain the same because you have moved the position of your `queueFront`. Again when you later modify the queue, by pushing 5, the contents of array become `1 2 3 5 0 0 0 0`. I would suggest that you implement a print function for the queue, so things can get simplified or at least you can see what are contents of your queue rather than contents of the array.

As far the implementation is concerned, it is slightly off the track as you can get a max. of 7 elements in the queue, instead of 8(as you would have expected). It is because you check for `((queueBack + 1 ) % arrayLength) == queueFront` when you are inserting at position `queueBack` in the array